# Lego Prototype or Megablok?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I came across this brick while sorting some Lego I purchased. It's similar to an [Electric, Light Bulb Cover (colored globe)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4773#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), but with three major differences. It is a bit wider, the lower lip is a bit higher, and rather than being mostly hollow (to receive a bulb) it is designed to receive a bar. I was unable to find the part when searching Bricklink's trans-red part list.

The inside has what appear to be a part number of 10780 and a mold identifier of 1-8. Given there is no Lego stamp I'm guessing it is a knockoff, but I'd like other opinions as I'm unsure whether prototype bricks are all marked. Given the source of the parts there is a small chance it is a prototype.

[image: Brick with antenna and trans-red reference]

[image: Part interior shot]

Comment: Not all Lego pieces say Lego - even some rather recent ones are unadorned. I keep wondering if I should ask a question about what the most recent is, once I have some good examples to show.

Comment: There was a question here not too long ago regarding parts without a Lego stamp. I recall there were a scant few recent examples, but apparently they do exist.

Answer (score 5):

I can no longer access the Bricks.SE account I used to submit the original question. But this piece is a Kreo element from the ["Space Dive" set](https://kreo.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Dive).

Comment: Great job on ID'ing the part :) To merge your accounts, take a look at the process described [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Play well!

Answer (score 2):

The finish of the piece and the numbering scheme reminds me of Megabloks pieces, but it is far from a 100% sure, definitive answer. After half an hour of searching on Google and on the Megabloks website, I have seen no such product that would contain this piece, but based on its apparent age, this information is still not decisive.

Comment: I also looked through some Megablok sets at Bricker and the closest thing I saw was a missile tip, but it was much larger. The numbering scheme is similar to both Lego which makes it difficult to determine. Thanks for your input!